# Is the "Maximum number of POST request parameters" limit trappable?

Tags: http, post, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

Coldfusion 10 allows a limit to be set for the maximum number of POST request parameters (Server Settings / Settings / Request Size Limits / Maximum number of POST request parameters).  The default limit is 100.

**Is it possible to trap when this limit has been exceeded so that it can be handled with a custom handler?**  If yes, how?

I've tried to trap it with a site wide error handler and an onError() method in Application.cfc.  Neither attempt was successful.

Thanks for looking.

Comment: Can you post the code used to try and trap the error in OnError?

Comment: I added a cflog to onError() to test if onError() was invoked when the limit was exceeded.  cflog didn't produce anything so it seems like onError() isn't being called.

Comment: A good way to see if onError() is being called is to run your code with a known error.  Missing semicolons usually suffice.

Comment: I can confirm what you are seeing. So far, the only option that has worked is [adding a custom error page in WEB-INF\web.xml](http://blogs.coldfusion.com/post.cfm/getting-started-with-tomcat-in-coldfusion-10), using `<error-code>500</error-code>`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can confirm the behavior you are seeing.  I *think* the exception is being thrown by the CF servlet, before Application.cfc is invoked, which would explain why `onError` never fires.

So far, the only option that worked for me is [adding a custom error page](http://blogs.coldfusion.com/post.cfm/getting-started-with-tomcat-in-coldfusion-10) in `WEB-INF\web.xml`, using an HTTP status code:

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>400</error-code>
    <location>/path/to/myErrorPage.cfm</location>
</error-page>
```

*Note: From the comments, @Adrian mentioned that he added the above to `\cfusion\runtime\conf\web.xml`, rather than the one in `web-inf\`.*

**Update 1:**

Further reading suggests you can also configure things at a more granular level. To handle a specific [kind of exception](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html), use `<exception-type>` instead of `<error-code>`. For example:

```
<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.Exception</exception-type>
    <location>/path/to/myErrorPage.cfm</location>
</error-page>
```

<strike>That said, in my (brief) test, CF10 appeared to use very general exception classes for this error. Both of which have many potential causes, not just posting too many form fields. So keep that in mind. Granted it is a bit more focused than handling all HTTP 500 errors, but it may still encompass other causes as well.</strike>

> ```
> javax.servlet.ServletException: ROOT CAUSE: 
>     java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call sendError() ..
> ```

**Update 2:**

Turns out the `javax.servlet.ServletException` was just a red herring. As @AdrianWright pointed out in the comments, that error is related to Debugging Settings. When CF generates the "Maximum number of POST request parameters" message, it does not properly account for debugging, which in turn causes a *new* exception: `java.lang.IllegalStateException`.  Hence the HTTP 500 error:

When debugging is disabled (as it would be on a production system) CF simply writes an error message directly to the response stream and returns HTTP status code 400. Since no exception is thrown, `<exception-type>` is useless here. So you are stuck with using status code:

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>400</error-code>
    <location>/path/to/myErrorPage.cfm</location>
</error-page>
```

However, on the custom error page, you can [extract the error message from the request stream](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/javax.servlet/javaxservleterrormessage.htm). Then handle it accordingly:

```
  <cfset req = getPageContext().getRequest()>
  <cfset message = req.getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.message")>

  <cfif message contains "POST parameters exceeds">
     Too many form fields. do something...
  <cfelse>
     Some other cause. do something else
  </cfif>
```

Comment: FYI `java.lang.IllegalStateException` appears to be related to Debugging & Logging / Debug Output Settings / Enable Request Debugging Output being enabled.  When it's disabled the 500 changes to a generic  400 page from Tomcat.

Comment: Ah! I was wondering about that last night, but did not have time to fully investigate. Just to confirm, when you disabled debugging, it still skips the site wide error handler? (I cannot test it right now)

Comment: Bummer. Any change in the exception reported in the logs - or still `javax.servlet.ServletException`? If would be great if it was something specific, so you could use `<exception-type>`, but I suspect that is too much to hope for ;-)

Comment: When Tomcat generates the 400 page, CF doesn't log any exception just a message in coldfusion-out.log.

Comment: If that is the case, I think you are stuck with using `<error-code>400</error-code>`. A very quick search suggests you can extract the error message from `getPageContext().getRequest()` via `getAttribute('javax.servlet.error.message')`. That returns "POST parameters exceeds the maximum limit".

Comment: Last comment (I think). I had to add the `<error-page>` snippet to `\cfusion\runtime\conf\web.xml`.  I'm using the built in web server with CF10.

Comment: I used a similar set up, and `web-inf\web.xml` did the trick, but I will update the post to mention that location, just in case.

Comment: Is there a way to set the post parameters limit to a specific page instead of it being a global settting?

Comment: @VictorRamos - No, AFAIK CF only offers an all-or-nothing setting.

Answer (score 0):

If the limit is exceeded, then there would be entries in the ColdFusion exception and application log.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't allow me to (easily) trigger a custom error handler.