# Coldfusion 503 service unavailable page

Tags: coldfusion, iis-6, windows-server-2003, coldfusion-9, windows-server

Recently one of my websites had ColdFusion stop responding. Instead of any pages, our users got 503 Server Error response.

What I want to be able to do is feed an "Offline" page to my users, so they're not staring at a blank screen.

I'm using Windows Server 2003, IIS 6, ColdFusion 9.

I see a lot of solutions for ASP.net, but I'm not entirely sure there's a "built-in" solution for my case.

Comment: As suggested below, I *think* it is configurable in IIS. If not - I do not have time to test this but try using assigning [custom error page in web.xml](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21273221/104223). Use `<error-code>503</error-code>` and obviously use a static html page.

Comment: @Leigh Thanks for the tip. It seems to be only working for ColdFusion 10 though.

Comment: No, `web.xml` is common to any servlet. So the paths may be a bit different in CF9, but it should work fine.

Comment: You can create a custom 503 page and save it inside your webroot. That  would always have some information, instead of error page

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used IIS 6 in awhile, but you should be able to change your error handlers in IIS to display a custom page when it sees a 503 error.

Comment: 503 doesn't seem to be changeable. http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/80cb8d8d-8fd8-4af5-bb3b-4d11fff3ab9c.mspx?mfr=true

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the 503 error in IIS for that site.
You can make it an HTML page, so you can make it look good, and be more user friendly than just an error.

That is what I recommend.

Comment: That error doesn't seem to be in the custom errors tab for IIS.