# Moved from Coldfusion 9 to 11 now Elements are Undefined

Tags: coldfusion, undefined, element, coldfusion-9, coldfusion-11

Everything worked find in CF9, but after moving to a new server with CF11, when I submit a form on one of my pages, I get an error about an "Element is Undefined" or "Variable is Undefined". These elements are created via a `cfloop` and when I look at the source code, the element does exist within the `cfform` tag. The `cfloop starts from 1 and goes through (in this case) 30. The prior elements 1-11 run fine upon submission but errors out at 12. I eliminated what were elements 1-3 to make sure there was no issue with the data that was 12. But still it errors out at 12 even though the data representing 12 is different than it was prior.

If I add `cfparam`s for everything, it'll throw 400 error on the page, but no error info goes into the CF log nor can I find it in the logs folder for HTML.

I'd list more but it's redundant from 1 through 30 within the `cfform` and considering all is well when `cfloop` writes the code from 1-11, I know it's not a user-error in a coding difference from 1-11 to 12.

Here is an example of the code:

```
<input type="Hidden" id="InvoiceID12" name="InvoiceID12" value="606410445">
<input type="Hidden" size="4" id="OrderID12" name="OrderID12" value="10811">
<select id="Status12" name="Status12" onChange="getlocationinfo(this.value, 'LocationID12')">
<option value="Order">Order</option>
<option value="">-----------</option>
<option value="Ordered">Ordered</option>    
<option value="Backordered">Backordered</option>
</select>
```

Any thoughts?

**Update**

I think there is something more going on here than originally thought. I removed all code from the submitted page and just put in the word 'test', but upon running the same page with the in place, it throws that obscure 400 error that I can't find a log for. When I run the page apart from the submit button, it loads fine with the 'test' message...?!

Comment: Do you have a screenshot of the error? Can you get a `<cfdump var="#form#">`

Comment: 400 The page you are trying to access can not be displayed. Please try again or notify the administrator.  
Dump does not display.

Comment: In your sample code, can you include the `<cfform>` tag AND the HTML that it generates?

Comment: (Edit) *obscure 400 error that I can't find a log for* Hmm... what is the exact error message (if you are using IE, disable "friendly" error messages to view the original message)?  Just a guess, but from what you described it sounds a lot like the error that occurs when one of the [Maximum POST limits (maximum parameters or size) is exceeded](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21269778/104223). IIRC, it only generates a 400 error on screen and does *not* generate an entry in the app logs.  How many fields/how much data is your form posting and what are the size limits listed in the CF Administrator?

Comment: Also, did you check the bug database? Hard to say if it is related without knowing your full version number and seeing [a stand-alone repro case](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), but a  quick search turned up issue #3816563: [CF requests return Error 400 after a post request has successfully completed](https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3816563)